# how to prevent crm 2011 form from reloading after save event

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

How can I prevent a crm 2011 form from reloading(refreshing). Actually I am saving a form in its `onLoad()` event. I collect all the passed parameters in form `OnLoad` event and then call the `OnSave` event of the form and it is successfully saved but after save it reload the form which my client don't want. Any help ....

Answer (score 1):

When you change a value inside a record and after you save it (by pressing the save button or by javascript code) the form will be always refreshed.

With the next Dynamics CRM release this behavior will change, already the new forms (introduced with Polaris update) do an autosave every 30 seconds without refreshing the form.

Comment: You could also intercept the onsave event, save the record behind the scenes with a JS call and then [stop the on save event](http://www.infinite-x.net/2011/05/06/crm-2011-canceling-the-save-operation/)